# Xamarin.Android, сохранение файла на sd для открытого доступа

Tags: android, xamarin, файловая-система

Как в Xamarin.Android сохранить файл на внешний источник(SD-карту)?

Есть задача сохранять файл так, чтобы потом пользователь мог работать с этим файлом на устройстве и вне приложения. К сожалению это нарушает политику iOS, поэтому там это невозможно, но из-за этого ограничен и Android в Xamarin

Код ниже - работающий, для сохранения файла в специализированном каталоге. Но этот каталог скрыт от пользователя и работать с этими файлами нельзя.

```
public class FileWorker_Android : IFileWorker
    {
        public Task DeleteAsync(string filename)
        {
            // удаляем файл
            File.Delete(GetFilePath(filename));
            return Task.FromResult(true);
        }

        public Task<bool> ExistsAsync(string filename)
        {
            // получаем путь к файлу
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            // существует ли файл
            bool exists = File.Exists(filepath);
            return Task<bool>.FromResult(exists);
        }

        public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetFilesAsync()
        {
            // получаем все все файлы из папки
            IEnumerable<string> filenames = from filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(GetDocsPath())
                                            select Path.GetFileName(filepath);
            return Task<IEnumerable<string>>.FromResult(filenames);
        }

        public async Task<string> LoadTextAsync(string filename)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText(filepath))
            {
                return await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }
        }

        public async Task SaveTextAsync(string filename, string text)
        {
            string filepath = GetFilePath(filename);
            using (StreamWriter writer = File.CreateText(filepath))
            {
                await writer.WriteAsync(text);
            }
        }
        // вспомогательный метод для построения пути к файлу
        string GetFilePath(string filename)
        {
            return Path.Combine(GetDocsPath(), filename);
        }
        // получаем путь к папке MyDocuments
        string GetDocsPath()
        {
            return Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        }
    }
```

Из [документации](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html?hl=ru) Android, вся работа с внешним источником(SD-картой) происходит через `Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory`, однако в Xamarin в `Environment` такого метода нет

Comment: https://diptimayapatra.wordpress.com/2013/07/10/xamarin-write-file-to-sd-card-in-android/ уверены, что нет?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё же такой метод есть, только получить его не так просто)
Дело было в пространстве имен. Чтобы получить доступ к этому методу, нужно, чтобы пространство имен в текущем классом совпадало с *MainActivity.cs* внутри проекта *Android*
Просто подключить Android не получалось
т.е. `namespace NameOfProject.Droid`

и тогда этот код будет работать

```
string GetDocsPath()
{
      return Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.Path;
}
```